# MVC 6 RedirectToAction not working behing proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a mvc6 app that runs behind a proxy, so I configured the proxy address like that:

```
 app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            var hostHeader = context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Host"];
            string serviceManagerHeader = string.Empty;
            if (hostHeader.Any())
            {
                serviceManagerHeader = 
    hostHeader.First().Substring(hostHeader.First().IndexOf('/') + 1);
            }
            context.Request.PathBase = hostHeader.Any() ? 
    $"/{serviceManagerHeader}".TrimEnd('/') ://from SM
            string.Empty;
            return next();
        });
```

and then everything works well in proxy but RedirectToAction not working anymore
Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: From [Configure ASP.NET Core to work with proxy servers and load balancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-7.0),  we see "When HTTPS requests are proxied over HTTP, the original scheme (HTTPS) is lost and must be forwarded in a header." Does that answer your question?

Comment: thanks for your comment, I did try it and didn't help, finally the problem was in the proxy, they didn't pass the headers well so after they fixed it -it's working